# How to run XnView MP Version 0.83 on Xubuntu 16.10?

Tags: apt, package-management, xubuntu, xnview

I just installed **XnView MP** version **0.83** from official site *Linux DEB 64bit* [package](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/#downloads). But the program cannot start. The error is the following:

```
/opt/XnView/XnView: error while loading shared libraries: libgstapp-0.10.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I googled the problem and I found the [following](http://newsgroup.xnview.com/viewtopic.php?f=82&t=32986). One proposed solution is:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dhor/myway
```

but there is no version of this PPA for my version of Ubuntu:

```
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Ubuntu/zesty
```

Another proposed solution is:

```
apt install libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0
```

But this package is missing for my version of Ubuntu. There is newer version of the package `libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0` which I had already installed.

I tried to create symbolic link with the name of the missing SO file referring the newer version.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstapp-1.0.so.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstapp-0.10.so.0
```

But now another SO file is missing:

```
/opt/XnView/XnView: error while loading shared libraries: libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I cannot find newer version of this file on my computer and I don't know from which package to install it.

Is it possible some kind of workaround to run **XnView** on my system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are talking about XnViewMP 0.83 and not XnView 1.73. This is how I got 64-bit version of XnViewMP 0.83 working after downloading it from the link you have provided (you can just copy and paste these commands after you have installed the .deb package):

```
cd /tmp/
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gstreamer0.10/libgstreamer0.10-0_0.10.36-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gst-plugins-base0.10/libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0_0.10.36-1_amd64.deb
dpkg -x libgstreamer0.10-0_0.10.36-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb libgstreamer0.10-0_0.10.36-1ubuntu1_amd64
dpkg -x libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0_0.10.36-1_amd64.deb libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0_0.10.36-1_amd64
sudo cp -av libgstreamer0.10-0_0.10.36-1ubuntu1_amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/* libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0_0.10.36-1_amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/* /opt/XnView/lib/
rm -rf libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0_0.10.36-1_amd64* libgstreamer0.10-0_0.10.36-1ubuntu1_amd64*
```

Above commands will download and put all needed libraries to XnViewMP lib folder.

I think this can be considered a bug, since XnViewMP shouldn't require libraries which do not exist anymore.

Comment: The final copy command seems wrong.

Comment: And to me it seems good. I just checked again and it worked as expected for me. If it does not for you, please say what exactly is not working for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get XnView from the [GetDeb](http://www.getdeb.net) repositories, which provide the `xnviewmp` package in version `0.83-1~getdeb1` at the time of writing, including a build for 16.10.

To set up the GetDeb Apps repository as software source for your 16.10 (Yakkety) system, run these two commands:

```
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb-apps.list <<< 'deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu yakkety-getdeb apps'
wget -q -O- http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then update your package lists:

```
sudo apt update
```

Now you can install XnView by simply running:

```
sudo apt install xnviewmp
```

Comment: I did the steps you described but there is an error: `The following packages have unmet dependencies: xnviewmp:i386 : Depends: xnviewmp-data:i386 (= 0.83-1~getdeb2~yakkety) but it is not installable`.

I successfully performed `sudo apt install xnviewmp-data` but the error is still present.

Comment: Uh oh. This seems to me like a packaging bug. Either there is only one `xnviewmp-data` package for all architectures, then the `xnviewmp:i386` should depend on that one instead of the nonexistent `xnviewmp-data:i386`, or they simply forgot to provide the data package for 32 bit. Sorry then, the only thing you can (and should) do here is probably to contact GetDeb and/or file a bug report. See http://www.getdeb.net/contact/