# XnViewMP wont start in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: xnview

I installed ubuntu 19.04 today and got the problem that XnView will not start.
It,s don't matter if I try from UI or terminal
Any ideas?

Regards

Anders

Comment: Can you add the output of `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` to your question, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The XnViewMP .deb file does not install a needed library.

To fix this open a terminal windows (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and enter the command

```
sudo apt install libopenal1
```

---

How I determined this:

When running `xnview` from a terminal, an error indicating the library `libopenal1.so.1` could not be found.  Using the tools at https://packages.ubuntu.com/ I was able to determine that the needed package is `libopenal1`

Comment: Thank you very much. Now Xnview starts.

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved the problem with start XnView. Now I have another problem. The GPS tab is empty. In previous versions, the problem could be solved by installing libssl1.0-dev. This seems not possible anymore. 
Do you know a solution to this problem also? :))

Comment: @AndersWeinberg Apparently you might need to view->RebuildThumbnails.  I don't have a camera with GPS, so I have to enter some (in EXIF data) - this resulted in the appearance of the GPS tab a little later on.

Comment: @AndersWeinberg If the answer that I wrote helped you, please consider marking it as 'accepted'!

Comment: Sorry I missed to mark your excellent answer accepted. I can start Xnview now but still the GPS tab Is empty. This problem I hade in Ubuntu 18.04 & 18.10 but it could be solved by installing libssl1.0-dev. I can not find libssl1.0-dev in synaptic, tus I can not install it. Rebuild of humbnails do not help.

Comment: I tested it in 19.04, and got the GPS tab after entering the data onto a picure (and restarting XnView) - I don't have libssl1.0 on that machine...  The equivalent package in 19.04 is `libssl-dev`

Comment: It seems that the gps info from the camera (Canon 6D MK II) is no longer read correct. I have the libssl-dev installed but no GPS info or map is visible...

Comment: @AndersWeinberg check way down in the exif data. If you need to collect it in bulk, you could use `exiftool`

Comment: What did you search in packages.ubuntu.com? I search xnview and it says my search has no results.

Comment: @aderchox I may have mis-typed the name of the library - it should have been `libopenal.so.1`  You can search package contents from the webpage, and if you search for the library specifically, the only package which comes up is `libopenal1`