# How to install XnViewMP on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, image-viewers

Is there a way to install Image Viewer and converter **XnViewMP** (or Xnview and XnConverter) in **Ubuntu 18.04**?
Other described ways ( [14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/511875/how-to-install-xnviewmp-in-ubuntu-14-04), [16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805269/how-to-install-xnview-in-ubuntu-16-04), [16.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868724/how-to-run-xnview-mp-version-0-83-on-xubuntu-16-10) , [18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030896/how-to-install-xnviewmp-in-ubuntu-18-04) ) seem not to work for me.

From [How to install XnViewMP in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030896/how-to-install-xnviewmp-in-ubuntu-18-04) isn't work for me:

```
$ snap search xnview
No matching snaps for "xnview"
```

Comment: @vanadium in my topic i already have a link on this ticket and description why this solution isn't work: No matching snaps for "xnview"

Comment: What happens when you try to install the `deb` from the XnView homepage?

Comment: Your question is identical to that asked there, so it is a duplicate. Further action and answers should go there. Anyway, there is a deb on the site, there is an app image, and all you tell us is that "it does not seem to work for you". That might be why someone even downvoted the question. That said, I have the appimage running already.

Comment: @vanadium identical but not same. I show in my message errors which solve message by link which you and another add for duplicate.

Comment: It's the **exact same question – copy/pasted**. Even the accepted answers are the same (download the deb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the .deb file (64 bit) from the XnViewMP website  https://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/#downloads

Double click in it in your file manager, and the software installer should open it up and install it for you.

Update:

The XnViewMP .deb file does not install a needed library.

To fix this open a terminal windows (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and enter the command

```
sudo apt install libopenal1
```

Comment: Clear installed Ubuntu 18.04. I download my **Linux DEB 64-bit** from https://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/, then Install it. Try run from App Menu -- nothing. App crashes after 5-10 sec after run.

Comment: Try the answer listed in [https://askubuntu.com/a/1143547/283721](https://askubuntu.com/a/1143547/283721)

Comment: thanks, **libopenal1** solve problem with .deb install!